# .NET build slows first page load significantly

Tags: asp.net, iis, pageload

I am working on a .NET WebForms application and I have observed that whenever I build, after the build, the very first page load takes longer to load than usually. This happens even if I wait after building before I load a page. Is there a way to increase human workforce performance by changing IIS/.NET to initialize things on postbuild instead of first page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle).
Quoting:

You can use Application Initialization Module which comes in-box with IIS 8.0, like this:

```
<applicationInitialization
     doAppInitAfterRestart="true" >
   <add initializationPage="/" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

This will send a request to the root of your app (initializationPage="/") every time your app starts automatically.

You can also configure the Start Mode for your application pool to **Always Running** which means every time IIS restarts, it will make sure to start your application pool immediately (this if from right click on your application pool then *Advanced Settings*).

Comment: Is this applicationInitialization to be added inside the appSettings node?

Comment: Nope, inside <system.webServer> because is an IIS function. Check this: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/applicationinitialization

Comment: Also, you need to install "Application Initialization" function under Windows features if is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Professional servers have hardly any latency, though it requires quite a bit of tweaking. Also, by default, applications recycle regularly on IIS (as well as when some kinds of exceptions occur, when some files are changed, or when some thresholds are reached). Professional web application hosting is anything but simple :) You might get help with that on Server Fault, perhaps.

Another option is to avoid mixing pre-compilation and JIT-compilation - if you only pre-compile, you don't need to do any compilation when the application is deployed, resulting in faster startup times. If you only deploy sources, the application domain doesn't need to be torn down when you make a change, which means that only the change needs to be recompiled, which is much faster.

And of course, ASP.NET Core is much, much faster in both scenarios - it can do the whole compilation in-memory, unlike the legacy system which uses `csc` to build multiple assemblies, save them to disk, *load* them from disk, merge them together, save that *again*, just to load it again and initialize.